# lldb 'step into' can't jump into function call on Xcode7?

Tags: ios, xcode7, lldb

I use Xcode7 to debug a App.

Seems `step into` behave like the `step over`, can't jump into the execution of a sub procedure? It's just jump to the next line in the source code each time.

And if I'm debug in the UIKit method(I don't have source code), it's jump to the next instruction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have found, `step-in` avoids frames with no debug information.  Most people like to just hit one step command, rather than switching between step & next depending on the line they are on, and in my experience, tend to choose `step`.  This is made more pleasant if the debugger doesn't stop in printf & other code you have no debug info for.

However, lldb's "step" command has an option to control this:

```
   -a <boolean> ( --step-in-avoids-no-debug <boolean> )
        A boolean value that sets whether stepping into functions will step over functions with no debug information.
```

If you use this frequently, you can either reset the `step` alias to include this option, or make another alias that includes it.  Use the `command alias` command to do this.

And if you always want step-in to step into code with no debug information, just set the global setting:

```
settings set target.process.thread.step-in-avoid-nodebug 0
```

either at the start of a debug session or in your .lldbinit.

Note, most of lldb's commands are documented in the `help` system.  For instance, `help step` would have shown the above option for the step command, and `apropos step` would have shown the setting.

Answer (score 0):

From [GDB Manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html):

> Also, the step command only enters a function if there is line number information for the function. Otherwise it acts like the next command. This avoids problems when using cc -gl on MIPS machines. Previously, step entered subroutines if there was any debugging information about the routine.

And I found `Step into` works well when I have source file.

So maybe I have make a mistake. But the lldb is very lack of documents.